# How to Automatically import external images to Upload

Tags: images, cache, cron, remote, autosave

Hi to all I would like to have a simple plugin, hook, anything that Automatically caches external images.
Simple explanation:
Actually I'm using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/
But with this I have to click on scan, then choose which images I would like to save then wait and so on...
I'm in need of something more automatic.
Is there anyone who can teach/tell me how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Cache Images plugin's thumbnails page on the WordPress plugin directory it looks like this feature already exists within the plugin. In the admin section of your site go to Settings→Media there should be an option to cache images when posts are saved.

[image: Cache Images settings for automatic caching]

Comment: What a blind man I am :-)
Thank you very much! I think I would never see it if you didn't tell me!